# How can I replace an advertisement on a website using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tampermonkey

There's a problem when I want to replace an advertisement via jQuery using the Tampermonkey extension.

The code I am using to replace the ad is:

```
$(".adsbygoogle").replaceWith('<div id="reklama" style="display: inline-block; width: 300px; margin-bottom: 10px; height: 250px;"><script>Ad Here</script<div>');');
```

But when I try to reach the website, it completely disables my extension.

When I try replacing the ad with an image, it worked.

```
$(".adsbygoogle").replaceWith('<div id="reklama" style="display: inline-block; width: 300px; margin-bottom: 10px; height: 250px;"><img src="http://example.com/imagehere.png"><div>');
```

Can you help?

Comment: is that because  u r missing an angle bracket in `<script>Ad Here</script<div>`?

Comment: AND... because `<script>Ad Here</script>` is not a script. Try: `<script>document.write("Ad Here");</script>`.... and `</div>` at the end.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette can't use `document.write` after page is loaded...wipes out whole page

Comment: Ok.. Right. so try : `<script>alert("Ad Here");</script>`... I repeat `</div>` at the end. You'lll kwow that a script can be executed.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette the ad doesn't show i tried using your method but still it disabled my extension.
Here is almost the same code i use:

`$(".adsbygoogle").replaceWith('<div><script>alert("<script type='text/javascript' src='//website.com/ad.php'></script>");</script><div>'); `


it still shows the problem

Thank you alot for replying

Comment: I found a solution for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have *missed* the **angle bracket**, while closing the `script` tag.

**Corrected:**

```
$(".adsbygoogle").replaceWith('<div id="reklama" style="display: inline-block; width: 300px; margin-bottom: 10px; height: 250px;"><script>Ad Here</script><div>');');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it.
The issue is the `</script>` tag within the string.

Since you use the `.replaceWith()` method within `<script></script>`...
The "replace" action is halted when it encounters the `</script>` of the string.
So it halts too soon.

**The solution is to escape this `</script>` with a backslash`<\/script>`!**

Try this:
It will show the whole script in an alert, has you already tried:

```
<script>
$(".adsbygoogle").replaceWith('<div><script>alert(\'<script type="text/javascript" src="//website.com/ad.php"><\\/script>\')\<\/script></div>');
</script>
```

***Notice*** the "double-escape" I did on one of them!
Also notice that I also had to escape some single quotes

So now, what you really want to do is to use this script instead of alerting it:
Here is your solution:

```
<script>
$(".adsbygoogle").replaceWith("<div><script type='text/javascript' src='//website.com/ad.php'><\/script></div>");
</script>
```